# Pick most repeated value via SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Has anyone worked on getting the most repeated value from an array or in a loop (Lookuprows) via SSJS Script Activity?

For example:

```
Var Array = [1,2,2,2,2,3,4]
```

The result should be 2.

I tried passing the SSJS array to a JS variable and getting the result but I would need to do a POST request again to pass it to a SSJS variable.

Comment: can you please clarify and/or give some use case examples. I am unsure what you mean by 'most repeated value' and 'passing the SSJS array to a JS variable' or 'POST request'. These terms are vaguely connected in your question and with clarity I might be able to better assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the mode (most repeated number inside an array) inside of SFMC SSJS, you can create a simple function, like so:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var array =  [1,2,2,2,2,3,4]

var mode = mode(array)

function mode(arr){
    var numMapping = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(numMapping[arr[i]] === undefined){
            numMapping[arr[i]] = 0;
        }        
            numMapping[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    var greatestFreq = 0;
    var mode;
    for(var prop in numMapping){
        if(numMapping[prop] > greatestFreq){
            greatestFreq = numMapping[prop];
            mode = prop;
        }
    }
    return parseInt(mode);
}

</script>
```

This will then have the SSJS var `mode` equal the Mode of the input array.

If you are trying to utilize this against a rowset, like what was returned via a lookup, you will run into a bit of an issue. At that point, it might be better to have a for loop run through that rowset and create an array that you then use to run through the above function.

---

**EDIT** - updated to provide function that works on Strings and Numbers:

```
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i];
        if(modeMap[el] == null)
            modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el]++;  
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    return maxEl;
}
```

Comment: This works fine for an array with numbers, but not for string. Sorry, I should have mentioned the string in the question. I have the solution now for strings too, Thanks :)

Comment: @AbhiReddyMusku - if you have a solution, could you please share as an answer so that any others that run into this issue can reference your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Gortonington for your time and Input. Below is the solution I'm referring to, works with both numbers and strings:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var arrAS=["Beds", "Mattresses", "Mattresses", "Beds", "Bedsheets", "Mattresses"]

var x = 1;
var y = 0;
var item;
for (var i=0; i<arrAS.length; i++)
{
        for (var j=i; j<arrAS.length; j++)
        {
                if (arrAS[i] == arrAS[j])
                 y++;
                if (x<y)
                {
                  x=y; 
                  item = arrAS[i];
                }
        }
        y=0;
}
Write(item) ;

</script>
```